# How to get the list of all apps on android device using terminal

Tags: java, android, terminal, adb

there is a command line to get package name:-

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

But how to get the list of all applications on the device

Answer (score 10):

Previously the command for listing installed packages used to be `pm list packages`. But as of Android nougat, the command has been deprecated. The new command to do the same is `cmd package list packages`.

Comment: The command has been deprecated, not removed. Currently, it executes the new command in the background.

Answer (score 9):

Your question already contains the answer in itself: Running a terminal, you enter the [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)). So simply omit that part (`adb shell`) from your command, and run the `pm` command directly:

```
pm list packages
```

should produce the very same output. `pm` isn't part of ADB (or the `adb shell`) command, but rather an executable shipping with Android: The **p**ackage  **m**anager. So you can use its full potential:

```
pm list packages [options] 
options:
   -f: See their associated file.
   -d: Filter to only show disabled packages.
   -e: Filter to only show enabled packages.
   -s: Filter to only show system packages.
   -3: Filter to only show third party packages.
   -i: See the installer for the packages.
   -u: Also include uninstalled packages.
   --user : The user space to query.
```

Enjoy!

Comment: very helpful ! used show system and enabled, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also to save list of apps to txt use this command:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f > d:\1.txt
```

or if you want to  save file to adb folder just use

```
adb shell pm list packages -f > installed-apps.txt
```