# Cannot exit Kiosk mode on Pepper's tablet

Tags: android, kiosk, pepper

Recently a Kiosk app was automatically downloaded onto Pepper tablet (Android-based).
I clicked it today and it went into a continuous loop whereby it attempts to load the default app but cannot find one, and the only button available is Retry.

I tried shutting down and restarting Pepper but that made no difference - it still automatically starts in Kiosk mode.

Any idea how one can exit this Kiosk mode?

Thanks in advance

Comment: please try to delete with ADB shell visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927124/android-studio-how-to-uninstall-apk-or-execute-adb-command-automatically-bef

Comment: Thanks Mohammad - but please note this is not an .apk that i have installed, this "Kiosk" app seems to be a native Android app (part of the OS), so not sure how I can uninstall it

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the Kiosk app? Where did it come from / what's it called? Can you try and get a list of all apps on the device list here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900697/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-apps-on-android-device-using-terminal

Comment: hi Dominic - the app is called Kiosk Client, it comes with the OS apparently

Answer (score 2):

Just got an answer from support so leaving this here for future reference:
To exit kiosk mode:
1.  Slide 3 fingers from the external left border to the center, then release.
2.  A grey transparent area will appear on the top left corner of the screen.
3.  Touch 5 times this area.

Thanks all for your help